# Filtering ListBox using combobox and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, listbox

I have a winform that includes a `ListBox` and a `Combobox`. In this `ListBox` appears a clients list on first run.

I want to filter the "Clients" in the `ListBox` with a `Combobox`.

To fill the `ListBox` using the string selected in the `Combobox` i'm using :

```
private void FillListBox()
{
    this.lstClient.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Client c in this.client)
    {
        if (this.cBox.Text == "All")
            this.lstClient.Items.Add(c.ToString());
        else
            if (this.cBox.Text == "Retail" && c.GetType() == typeof(RetailClient))
                this.lstClient.Items.Add(c.ToString());
    }

    this.lstClient.Sorted = true;
}
```

After that i call this method from the event of the ComboBox :

```
private void cBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FillListBox();
}
```

It works "great" but my code is not really dynamic and too long (lots of differents clients) that's why i would like to use LINQ. 
I read on microsoft's documentation but i'm pretty confused on how using it.

Does anyone have some times to show me the way ?

*Adding infos :*

My form :

[image: Graphical]

I select the type i want in the ComboBox :

[image: ComboBox]

The result :

[image: Result]

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you're filtering your list. Could you give a graphical example?

Comment: What is `this.client`? Why do you need to use `GetType()` to determine the `type`? Is it a `List<object>` by chance? You can set the `ListBox.DataSource` filtering the source list with a simple LINQ query.

Comment: Yes this.client is a List<client> where client is a class. I'm using the 'type' because in my List<cient> there is multiple sort of clients (Retail, wholesale, ...)

Comment: Could you post your `Client` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's give it a try. If you want to implement filtering you should think about a proper structure how to represent your filter criterion. In this case you have a label in your combobox which is bound to a unique filter criterion. This could be represented by a custom class:

```
public class SortingRepresentation
{
    public string DisplayLabel { get; set; }
    public Type ClientType { get; set; }        
}
```

Now you can create a List of those criteria and shove it into the combobox:

```
List<SortingRepresentation> sortingFields = new List<SortingRepresentation>();

public Form1()
{
    sortingFields.Add(new SortingRepresentation{ DisplayLabel = "All", TypeCriterion = typeof(Client) });
    sortingFields.Add(new SortingRepresentation{ DisplayLabel = "Only Retail", TypeCriterion = typeof(Client_A) });
    sortingFields.Add(new SortingRepresentation{ DisplayLabel = "Only Wholesale", TypeCriterion = typeof(Client_B) });
    sortingFields.Add(new SortingRepresentation{ DisplayLabel = "Only Human Wholesale", TypeCriterion = typeof(Client_C) });

    cBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayLabel";
    cBox.DataSource = sortingFields;
}
```

When the selection changes in the combobox you can catch now the selected item (which will be of type `SortingRepresentation` and pass it as a filter to `FillListBox`:

```
private void cBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillListBox((SortingRepresentation)cBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

Now you can use the `Type TypeCriterion` inside this object to filter your list:

```
private void FillListBox(SortingRepresentation sortcriterion)
{
    this.lstClient.DataSource = null;

    this.lstClient.DataSource = client
            .Where(x => x.GetType() == sortcriterion.TypeCriterion || // either you are of this type
                        x.GetType().BaseType == sortcriterion.TypeCriterion // or your parent is of this type
                   ).ToList();
}
```

Since you are using a listbox, you can bind the sorted list directly to the `DataSource` and be done with it. For the proper display, you need to override the `ToString` method in your `Client` class and the `ListBox` will take care of the display accordingly. But as I see you've done it already

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It's not LINQ based but seems pretty better than mine.

Comment: @Nan0 the solution is entirely linq based. Have a look at the filtering. The best way of saying thank you on So is to mark the answer as accepted. Happy coding

Comment: I don't realize it was sorry. So i asked one Linq based solution and i got it thanks again !